# How do I get sum totals for BUY and SELL entries for specific dates in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, worksheet-function

I'm looking to get the difference (profit) between BUY and SELL for each day (column A). I've managed to get overall difference between BUY and SELL for all days but would like have each day calculated in totals per day in B:9 to B11.

So far I have this formula below but it just calculates total difference on all days between BUY and SELL In Column B.

=SUMIF(C:C,"*SELL*",H:H)-(SUMIF(C:C,"*BUY*",H:H))

How can I alter this function to reference the totals only for the specific date in column A?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution with two functions:

[image]

### 1. Get list of dates

Formula in `E2` with `QUERY` to get all unique dates:

`=QUERY(A2:A, "SELECT MAX(A) WHERE A != '' GROUP BY A LABEL MAX(A) ''")`

### 2. Get difference between "SELL" and "BUY"

Formula in `F2` with `ARRAYFORMULA` to get difference between "SELL" and "BUY":

`=IF(ISBLANK($E2),"",ARRAYFORMULA(SUM(IF(EQ(A2:A,$E2),IF(B2:B = "SELL", C2:C, MINUS(0, C2:C)),0))))`

Drag this formula down to all needed cells in `F` column.

#### Note:

format of "*Date*" column should be set to "*Plain text*", format of "*Order Price*" values should be "*Number*".

Comment: That's just what I was looking for.  Works great.  Thanks.